# Class that implements comparable

Tags: java, comparable

I'v a class Person I know I can make it comparable override compareTo method etc. I have a task to create anther class which can compare this persons.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String middleName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public Person(){}   


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.lastName.hashCode() + this.name.hashCode() + this.age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (middleName == null) {
            if (other.middleName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!middleName.equals(other.middleName))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.name = nama;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well what do you want to compare by? Last name? First name?

Comment: well I think by ages

Comment: Well then implement a `compareTo` method that does that... it's not clear exactly where you're having problems.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that in another class, not in class Person.

Comment: Oh, right. Then you implement Comparator rather than Comparable.

Comment: Thanks Jon, otherwise I was wondering how I could pass 2 objects to compareTo method ))

Comment: is this wrong ?

`public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
  Integer first = person1.getAge();
  Integer second = person2.getAge();
  return first.compareTo(second);
 }`

Comment: That should be fine - but you should basically edit your question telling us exactly what you've tried and what happened. Remember to implement `Comparator<Person>`

Comment: You mean in the feature ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the feature - but the main post. Not just in comments. At the moment, your question doesn't explain what problem you're having.